# How can i pass and get the value from datepicker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server-2005, ruby-on-rails-3

im noob to rails. how can i get the value from my datepicker to pass it to the another method so i can run my query.

**here's my controller:**

```
def index
    redirect_to(:action => 'step1') 
end

def step1
    @checkin = params[:checkin]
    @checkout = params[:checkout]
end

def step2
    checkin = @checkin
    checkout = @checkout
    @amenities = Amenity.available(checkin, checkout)
end
```

**my view**:

```
    <%= label_tag @checkin, "From:" %>
    <%= text_field_tag "checkin", @checkin %>
    <%= label_tag @checkout, "To:" %>
    <%= text_field_tag "checkout", @checkout %>

    <%= button_to "Show Availability", :action => "step2" %>
```

**and my model where i ran my query:**

```
scope :available, lambda {
    |checkin, checkout| { 
      :select => 'amenities.*',
      :order => 'id',
      :conditions => ["
        amenities.id NOT IN 
        (
          SELECT aa.id from amenities aa, amenity_list al WHERE
          amenities.id = al.amenities_id AND
          (
            (? BETWEEN al.checkin AND al.checkout) OR
            (? BETWEEN al.checkin AND al.checkout)
          )
        )", 
        checkin, 
        checkout
      ] 
    }
  }
```

HELP! thanks.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the session to store between several steps.
Also check out form wizard plugins / gems, which may can also do the job for you.

https://github.com/adkron/actsaswizard

CheckOut also this Screencast, which helps you may be:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms

Comment: i think this is not applicable for my app.. because im using a cart too. im using more than one model. :(

Comment: then store it in an object (cart) or so? I still would do it with a session / special model for that